# Unique and Non-Nullable using EF Core Fluent config

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

How should I enforce, using EF Core fluent configuration, a property, that is *not* the primary key, to be

```
a) UNIQUE &
b) NON NULLABLE
```

(edited from:

In the EF Core 5.0 fluent configuration, does the [`HasAlternateKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasalternatekey?view=efcore-5.0) imply [`IsRequired`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder.isrequired?view=efcore-5.0), or I should add the two on the same constraint?

PS.. I saw the property becames read-only, so the question moves on the [`HasIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasindex?view=efcore-5.0) method...)

```
var book = modelBuilder.Entity<Book>();
book.HasIndex(p => p.Code);
book.Property(p => p.Code).IsRequired();
```

Comment: I think you'd just make a unique index, and ensure the property is not null in the usual manner of Required https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `.IsUnique()` to the `HasIndex` method.

So:

```
var book = modelBuilder.Entity<Book>();
book.HasIndex(p => p.Code).IsUnique();
book.Property(p => p.Code).IsRequired();
```

HasAlternateKey DOES imply uniqueness, however EF keys cannot be changed, but properties that are part of an index CAN have the values changed, even if the index is unique. The unique index (in MSSQL at least...) will be enforced by the database preventing you from inserting duplicate values.